# How to extract text from 2 tags of html or replace first and last tag

Tags: python, regex

I have text like below

- I m just trying to extract the content from `p` tag
- I don't want to eliminate the `<p>` or any other tag between them

```
d = "<p><p>{'Area': 'Square',</p>\n<p> <tr> <td>'Flag': 'com'}</p></p>"
```

My code is below

```
import re
re.sub('<[^<>]+>', '',d)
```

My output is

```
"{'Area': 'Square',\n\xa0\xa0'Flag': 'com'}"
```

Expected out is only replace first `p` and last `p` tag

```
"<p>{'Area': 'Square',</p>\n<p> <tr> <td>'Flag': 'com'}</p>"
```

Comment: Regex isn't the right way to go about getting the inner elements of HTML, consider using something like https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: Well, `re.sub(r'^<p>|</p>$', '', d)` does it, but if you are sure the string starts and ends with these tags, you may  simply get the substring from the `d`. Regex does not seem something absolutely necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'^<p>(.*)</p>$', r'\1', d, flags=re.S)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/CgpN1m/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <p>                      '<p>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  </p>                     '</p>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```